# How to set a global validation for any Temporal field, parameter or form element received or saved by my Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I would like to implement a Global validation on all `Temporal` type objects received or (alternatively) saved in DB by my Spring Application. This includes `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` but may include any other, which is why I'd like to implement it once for all sub classes of `java.time.temporal.Temporal`.

For full disclosure I need to validate that all values are after "today - 5 years" and before "today + 5 years". But if this global validation is possible we plan on leveraging it for other conditions and types.

This include checking dates that are received as request parameters, path parameters, part of form data or json objects in API requests' bodies.
Basically anyway and any format I can receive dates from need to be checked against the above validation logic.

I have a lot of API endpoints to maintain and I have just as many (if not more) controller methods and request body to objects mappings that comes with those. So I am trying to see if there is a solution that uses only 1 validator and applies it whenever a date is found.

Also acceptable: doing that for all the Temporal fields saved by my entities (but this would be my second choice).

I have tried custom validators and it words (both through `initBinder` and applied through custom annotations) the big problem is to maintain the explicitly added configurations for all endpoints and also make sure that my team in the future will not forget to add this to their endpoint. Which is why I would like it to be set globally as a default, bonus would be to be to skip it explicitly for some very rare endpoints.